# The best way to calculate (javascript) pixels from a unit representation (rem/vh/px/...)

Tags: javascript, pixel, unit-conversion

Looking for a simple yet robust way to calculate pixel length from any string such as: "55rem" / "33vh" / "300px" to the current browser in pixels.

From what I understand there is window.getComputedStyle(), but I don't want the style to be attached to any actual element. So, considering I don't care about percentage of any element calculated, just simple unit conversion (relative to the current user browser/zoom) - it should be simple to be reasonably calculated by some pseudo element?

There are some solutions out there involving the actual calculation of the units, yet I believe there must be a simpler 3 liner solution (probably using getComputedStyle or similar function) for this...

Update:
Maybe it's not meant to be done in JS. Or simply, not the best practice... That would be an answer too. Just checking on a go/no go for this ...

Comment: Could you please clarify this: `but I don't want the style to be attached to any actual element`?

Comment: It has to be `attached to any element` since `em`, for example, depends on the elements font size.

Comment: anyway, you can use properties `.clientWidth` and `.clientHeight`

Comment: What is the intended use for the calculated value, will it be used to set the size of some element? If so, maybe the [CSS calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) can do what you need?

Comment: I mean only the simple sizes... rem, vh, vw, px. Not em, or at least not a specific element (html body would do...).

Answer (score 2):

`getComputedStyle` is a very expensive operation, as it triggers a CSS reflow every time you call it. I'd recommend calculating the conversions by hand, using things like `window.innerHeight` or `document.body.style.fontSize` (if it's set inline, that is).

If you use Webpack, you can even load [SCSS variables](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/sxbrscjuqu-share-scss-variables-with-javascript) to get the `body` font-size.